# SQL Group By and Count function

Tags: sql, pivot, crosstab

I hv the following db table and I would like to count and group by the Color. I am a year one student and beginner of SQL. Can anyone teach with the code?

SQL-CountColor:

[image: SQL-CountColor]

What I have tried:

```
Select COLOR,
  sum(case when Blue = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as Blue_count,
  sum(case when Red then 1 else 0 end) as Red_count,
  sum(case when Yellow then 1 else 0 end) as Yellow_count,
  sum(case when Black then 1 else 0 end) as Black_count,
  sum(case when Green then 1 else 0 end) as Green_count,
from TAB_GROUP
group by COLOR;
```

Comment: Have you tried anything atall?

Comment: This is not how StackOverflow works, and let me say that this is not how you will learn SQL (or anything else). Questions like this have been already asked multiple times on multiple sites (SO included), all you have to do is a bit of research. If after doing so you still won't be able to solve this, come back here and post a question describing what you tried and what's wrong with it, and you'll find help. Keywords tip: search "group by", "count", "case", "pivot" and you may find interesting resources.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to post what I tried

Comment: Select COLOR,
  sum(case when Blue = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as Blue_count,
  sum(case when Red then 1 else 0 end) as Red_count,
  sum(case when Yellow then 1 else 0 end) as Yellow_count,
  sum(case when Black then 1 else 0 end) as Black_count
sum(case when Green then 1 else 0 end) as Green_count
from TAB_GROUP
group by COLOR;

Comment: Edit your question with that code and format it, don't use comments for that

Comment: What's wrong with the query you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your query is that you're mixing two approaches, both valid but not compatible.

The first one is using a `case` statement, like @LONG did in its answer, and it's fine but doesn't require `group by`; you're already "artificially" grouping by giving different condition in each column;

```
select  sum(case when Blue = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as Blue_count,
        sum(case when Red then 1 else 0 end) as Red_count,
        sum(case when Yellow then 1 else 0 end) as Yellow_count,
        sum(case when Black then 1 else 0 end) as Black_count,
        sum(case when Green then 1 else 0 end) as Green_count
from    TAB_GROUP
```

The other approach is using a `group by`, and it's fine as well, but you will only have to count the rows for each group

```
select  COLOR, count(*) as CNT
from    TAB_GROUP
group by COLOR
```

This will give you a result that is the same as the desired one but with rows and columns inverted

```
COLOR  | CNT 
Blue   | 2
Red    | 2
Yellow | 1
Black  | 1
Green  | 1
```

To move rows to columns you would need a pivoting function, whose syntax may vary depending on the database you're using. This makes this approach more complex, but also more versatile in case the number of possible values increases.

Answer (score 1):

You should have searched a little bit, it's a very common SQL statement.

```
select COLOR, count(*) from TAB_GROUP group by COLOR
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select     sum(case when color = 'blue' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Blue',
           sum(case when color = 'red' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Red',
           sum(case when color = 'yellow' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Yellow',
           sum(case when color = 'Black' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Black',
           sum(case when color = 'Green' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Green'
From Table
```

Comment: @Rahul, not really, answered on my phone actually.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is basically right.  All you need to do is remove the `GROUP BY` and fix the `case` to refer to columns in your data:

```
select sum(case when color = 'Blue' then 1 else 0 end) as Blue_count,
       sum(case when color = 'Red' then 1 else 0 end) as Red_count,
       sum(case when color = 'Yellow' then 1 else 0 end) as Yellow_count,
       sum(case when color = 'Black' then 1 else 0 end) as Black_count,
       sum(case when color = 'Green' then 1 else 0 end) as Green_count
from TAB_GROUP;
```